Git personal access token issue
I am trying to push my repo after changes after 2FA enabled and even after using the Personal access token git throwing back an error on me?
git push https://username:password@github.com/zain171m/Portfolio.git
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/zain171m/Portfolio.git/'

I double checked the personal access token and it is valid as well

I advise you change your github password as soon as possible.

While your credentials have been redacted now, they might have been exposed in the meantime and you should change your password as soon as you can.

the credentials that i posted on stackoverflow was not legitimate already


Create classic Personal Access Token(PAT) with repo and workflow scopes

Define an environment variable to hold your PAT
PAT=ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

git push https://$PAT@github.com/zain171m/Portfolio.git


PAT identifies you as a user
NOTE: you only need workflow scope if your repo has GitHub Actions workflow under .github/workflows
